# Adding item to listbox from second form

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm trying to add items to a listbox from another form. Form1 has a listbox with a "Dummy" item, and when I try to add more items from that form, everything works fine. However, when I try to add items from a different form (AddContact.cs), no items are being added. I will supply code from both forms.

PS: The listbox is set to public, to be able to access it from outside Form1.

Form1:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list_names.Items.Add("Dummy");
    }

    private void btn_check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (list_names.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No item has been selected.", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else if (list_names.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Dummy")
        {
            //Dummy code for testing
            MessageBox.Show("Dummy has been selected!");
        }
    }

    private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AddContact().Show();
    }

    private void btn_remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Remove items from listbox
    }
```

AddContact:

```
    Form1 form;

    public AddContact()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form = new Form1();
    }

    private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No input has been given.");
        }
        else
        {
            //This doesn't work
            string s = textBox1.Text;
            form.list_names.Items.Add(s);
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you creating new form in `AddContact`, You need the reference to `Form1`.

```
Form1 form;

public AddContact(Form1 frm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form = frm;
}
```

and also

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new AddContact(this).Show();
}
```

Comment: just for knowledge: what happens in this due to : Form1 form;

public AddContact(Form1 frm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form = frm;
}

Answer (score 0):

A little workaround is an eventhandler

Just derive your own EventArgs

```
public class AddItemEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Item { get; set; } 
}
```

And add this code to your AddContanct-Form:

```
public event EventHandler OnAddItemNeeded(object sender, AddItemEventArgs);
```

In the `btn_add_click` method you have to trigger this event:

```
this.OnAddItemNeeded(this, new AddItemEventArgs() { Item = textBox1.Text });
```

When calling a new instance of AddContact in Form1:

```
AddContact ac = new AddContact();
ac.OnAddItemNeeded += new EventHandler(this.OnAddItemNeeded);
ac.Show();
```

And a handler that does the work within Form1:

```
private void OnAddItemNeeded(object sender, AddItemEventArgs e)
{
    list_names.Items.Add(e.Item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static List<string> lst=new List<string>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if (lst != null)
            listBox1.DataSource = lst;
    }
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {             
         Form1.lst.Add(textBox1.Text);
         textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
       }
 }
```

Comment: both form codes are written together, kindly separate them at the  time of use.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you initialize Form1 in AddContact constructor, that is the problem.

Try this:

AddContact:

```
Form1 form;

public AddContact(Form1 f)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form = f;
}

private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No input has been given.");
    }
    else
    {
        string s = textBox1.Text;
        form.list_names.Items.Add(s);
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

And add button:

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new AddContact(this).Show();
}
```